# assign tags to all posts

Tags: wordpress, tags

I want to auto assign some tags to a post category

I am using the wp set post tags function in the functions.php file.

```
wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, 'tag1,tag2', true );
```

It works when I put in the post id number. I need help with looping through the posts from a category.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write query and then apply the function for it. Let me share coding for this.

For custom post type and taxonomy the following code will work. Make sure to replace post_type , taxonomy and terms according to your value.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy_name',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => array(1,2,3),
            ),
        ),
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

For post type post there the query is simple

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'category__in'   => array(11,12,13)
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Make sure to replace category__in with category id you want to run the query.

After that please run the loop

```
<?php
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
               wp_set_post_tags( $the_query->post->ID, 'tag1,tag2', true );
        }

        } else {
            // No post found
        }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Then you should mark the reply as perfect answer so it can help many people to confirm which reply works :)